# How to Uninstall Django from MS Windows 10?

Tags: python, django, windows, command

I command
I deleted Django using `pip uninstall django`. But it did not install again.

The error message is:

> C:\Django>python -m pip install -U pip
> Requirement already up-to-date: pip in c:\python\lib\site-packages (19.2.3)

I don't know which command to use to completely remove and reinstall.

Comment: Try upgrading your pip by `python -m pip install –upgrade pip` then run the command `pip uninstall dango`

Comment: That's the command to update Pip. Use `python -m pip uninstall django` and then `python -m pip install django`

Comment: @harshitverma Their Pip is up-to-date, the message is there.